# Checking for group membership in Active Directory using LDAP and PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am pretty new to LDAP and Active Directory, and I think this should be a simple question. I am connecting to AD using the following code:

```
$ad = ldap_connect("domain.com") or die("Could not connect to AD");
//bind to the server
$uname = $uid . "@domain.com";
if (!ldap_bind($ad, "$uname", "$pwd") and $uid != "guest") {
    code...
}
```

and I need to check to see if the user is a member of one of three groups: ECSDocket_Admin, ECSDocket_User, or ECSDocket_Viewer. I have been searching around and most of the answers I have found use CN= and DN= and DC= in their queries, but I don't know what those mean. If someone could explain how it works, and what I need to do to figure out the group membership, that would be awesome!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP#Directory_structure

Comment: Thanks for that, but how would I then use that in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php

Comment: How do I figure out what the groups are called? Can I find that within AD, or are all groups called 'groups', all users called 'fullname', etc. to make the filter (&(groups=ECSDocket_Admin)(fullname=John Doe))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone cares, I was able to do a search like this:

```
$dn = "CN=$uid,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";
$filter = "(memberOf=CN=ECSDocket_Admin,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com)";
$justthese = array("memberOf");

$sr = ldap_search($ad, $dn, $filter, $justthese);
$info = ldap_get_entries($ad, $sr);
echo $info["count"]." entries returned.\n";
```

And by checking the count, I was able to determine if the inputted username was a part of the group -- if there was one, then it was a part of the group since I had already used ldap_connect under that username to check if it was valid within AD. For the filter, since memberOf is an array you need to specify the entire path. For example if you just needed to query the sn (surname) you could just have something like:

```
$filter = "(sn=smith)";
```

A site that helped me know exactly the right attributes was this one: http://www.selfadsi.org/user-attributes-w2k8.htm

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with PHP's implementation of accessing LDAP/Active Directory so I can't help you there.  What I can help you with is perhaps understanding where to get information from your domain structure in order to coherently assemble all those CN's, OU's, DN things.

Log into the console of one of your domain controllers and open the "Active Directory Users and Computers" administrator tool.

In the left window pane at the top will be the name of your domain, eg: somedomain.com
Take note of your domain name.

Now you need to find the location of the ECSDocket_Admin, ECSDocket_User, and ECSDocket_Viewer group objects within your domain structure.

Click on the +(plus) sign next to your domain name (if it isn't already).  You should see a bunch of folders (actually OU's and Directory's but I'll keep it simple).  The groups you are looking for will be located inside one of these 'folders', most likely inside the one called 'users' so start looking there.

Take note of the "path" to where you found the group, starting from the top 'somedomain.com' and working down through the folders.  eg:  somedomain.com/users/etc/ECSDocket_Admin

To query a group object you will need to know it's distinguished name (DN).  Using the info you collected about your domain name and the location you can assemble the DN for 
each of your groups like so:

Note:  I am using an example path to a group of: somedomain.com/users/etc/ECSDocket_Admin

DN value is:  **CN=ECSDocket_Admin,OU=etc,OU=users,DC=somedomain,DC=com**

--Notice that we are starting with the object name 'ECSDocket_Admin' and working our way UP the tree (reverse order when looking at the path I had you write down)!

--Notice that just the group name is prefixed with CN=

--Notice that all the 'folder' names are prefixed with OU=

--Notice that we split our domain name at the dot delimiter and prefixed each of those parts with a DC=

--Notice that everything in the DN value is delimited with a comma(,)

Values for other items you will probably need are:

The 'search base' or the point within the directory to start your search, using a domain name of somedomain.com as an example, will be: **DC=somedomain,DC=COM**

The search scope will be: **sub** which simply says it is ok to look in all those 'folders' underneath the starting point too

Once you figure out how to query a group object, the attribute value you are specifically interested in is called 'member'.  This attribute contains multiple values, one for each user that is a member of the group.  These values will be the DN of the user account.  The part you will be interested in will be the CN=SOMEUSER portion at the beginning as this is the users account name.  the rest is the 'path' to where this account object is stored in the domain structure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I still can't get it to work, but this helped me understand what is going on. The only thing I am still a little confused by is what exactly the names of the categories are. For example, for Users, to I check against the field Users, or fullname, or what?

Comment: When searching for users you will use the CN to search for them in order to obtain their DN. If you know exactly where they are sitting in the directory then you can use the DN straight away.  In either case, once you have the DN you can query that user object to get all the attribute values.  The attributes of a user object are the fullname, phone, etc..  Do a google search on AD user attributes and you'll find a lot of sites that list all that are available.  Tip: attributes names must be spelled exactly as defined,  some get a little crazy looking.

Comment: Thanks! It's not working perfectly yet, but the search isn't failing!